# Function that takes a vector and returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector

so I have a mini assignment and 1 of the question is as such: In a 100-floor building, a lift starts from the 1st floor and along the way, it stops at different floors to pick up people. This are the floors the lift stops at: 1(the start), 5, 14, 29, 80, 99. Find the difference between each floor the lift stops at.

I have to use as many concepts we learn in class as possible in this mini assignment. So I plan to use a vector (as a container to contain the different number of floors), a function (to calculate the difference between each floor) and returning back an array to print the difference.

How do I write a function which takes a vector, perform some calculations (adjacent_difference in my case) and then return an array.

This is how I would've done it if I were to return another vector, but I do not know how to tweak it to make it return an array instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> calculateDiff (std::vector<int> v);

int main() 
{
  std::vector<int> vec {1, 5, 14, 29, 80, 99};

  for(auto iterator = vec.begin(); iterator != vec.end(); ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << "Floors the lift stop at: ";
    std::cout << *iterator << std::endl;
  }

  std::vector<int> diff = calculateDiff(vec);

  for(auto iterator = diff.begin(); iterator != diff.end(); ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << "Floor Difference: ";
    std::cout << *iterator << std::endl;
  }
}

std::vector<int> calculateDiff (std::vector<int> v)
{
  std::vector <int> floorDiff;

  floorDiff.resize(v.size());
  std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end(), floorDiff.begin());
  floorDiff.erase(floorDiff.begin()); //First element does not give the difference

  return floorDiff;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to return an array instead of a vector?

Comment: *I have to use as many concepts we learn in class as possible* -- That doesn't mean you throw everything into an incoherent salad bowl of C++ syntax.  With what you wrote, you should be returning a vector, not an array.

Comment: As a good first approximation `[]` arrays *should not be used*. (`std::array` arrays do have their place)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `std::vector` as the return type is the best strategy, IMO. However, you'll have to tweak your function a little bit. You have to make sure that `floorDiff` is as large as `v`.

```
std::vector <int> floorDiff(v.size());
```

That is necessary since `std::adjacent_difference` does not allocate memory.

If you must return an array for whatever reason, you can simply expand your function a bit.

```
// Pass the input by const& to avoid the cost of a copy
// and to indicate that it won't be modified in the function.
int* calculateDiff (std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    std::vector <int> floorDiff(v.size());

    floorDiff.resize(v.size());
    std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end(), floorDiff.begin());

    int* arr = new int[floorDiff.size()-1];
    std::copy(floorDiff.begin()+1, floorDiff.end(), arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Make sure to deallocate the memory in the calling function.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to teach new people stuff without really explaining it... Especially with stuff like dynamic arrays.

Comment: @FeiXiang, I assume the OP knows how to deal with dynamically allocated memory. If they don't, I hope they will ask for clarification.

Comment: Additionally, you now have no way to know the size of your array besides looking the the size of your vector after returning, which is potentially dangerous since you are passing the vector by reference, which could change size.

Comment: @Isaac, I changed the argument to a `const&` so it won't be modified. Regarding the size, yes, the user has to know what they are doing when the decide they want to use a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel a need to use both an array and a vector, it's "more C++" to do it the other way around - passing an "array" (i.e. a pointer and a size) and returning a vector.
You also get to do some pointer arithmetic and illustrate the generality of `<algorithm>` in `calculateDiff`.

```
std::vector<int> calculateDiff (const int* v, size_t size)
{
  std::vector<int> floorDiff{size};
  std::adjacent_difference(v, v + size, floorDiff.begin());
  floorDiff.erase(floorDiff.begin())
  return floorDiff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::vector` throughout is the correct choice, but there are some style issues that you can improve

```
int main() 
{
  // vec is undescriptive of what it represents
  std::vector<int> floors {1, 5, 14, 29, 80, 99};

  for(auto iterator = floors.begin(); iterator != floors.end(); ++iterator)
  {
    // << can be chained
    std::cout << "Floors the lift stop at: " << *iterator << std::endl;
  }

  // Note that you repeat the "Floors the lift stop at: " 
  // If you only want one line, you can instead:      
  /* 
  std::cout << std::cout << "Floors the lift stop at: ";
  std::copy(floors.begin(), floors.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  */

  std::vector<int> diffs = calculateDiffs(vec);

  for(auto iterator = diffs.begin(); iterator != diffs.end(); ++iterator)
  {
    std::cout << "Floor Difference: " << *iterator << std::endl;
  }
  // and again, can std::copy into a std::ostream_iterator
}

std::vector<int> calculateDiffs (std::vector<int> values)
{
  // values is already a copy, as you passed by value
  std::adjacent_difference(values.begin(), values.end(), values.begin());
  values.erase(values.begin()); //First element does not give the difference

  return values;
}
```